# Mysql Having sum = 0 return 0 rows

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user.id, CONCAT(lastname, firstname), year, month, date FROM user
LEFT JOIN adoption ON user.id = adoption.adopter
GROUP BY user.id

id  CONCAT(lastname, firstname) year    month   date
16  Mr.A                        2016    6       25
17  Mr.B                        2016    6       18
18  Mr.C                        NULL    NULL    NULL
19  Mr.D                        NULL    NULL    NULL

//after, I add this, should return Mr.A, C, D
HAVING SUM(CONCAT(year,month,date)= 2016618 ) = 0
```

I have a query LEFT JOIN two tables user info table & their schedule table

I try to find out who don't have schedule on 2016618

I have used HAVING SUM, but it return 0 rows

is any know where is the problems?

Comment: try wrapping 2016618 in quotes, as I believe concat returns a string.

Comment: Try adding `COUNT(*)` as a result column. I bet there is more than one row for id 17. You should instead just write `HAVING year = 2016 AND month = 6 AND date = 18`. I mean, you can't sum dates. What does April 1, 2016 + July 19, 2020 even mean? *(other than Aprils Fool)*

Comment: having year = 2016... this will return the person who have schedule on that day, but I need to return peoples who don't

Comment: Store dates using a proper date data type.

Answer (score 1):

I try on my local server and @Jhecht is right, CONCAT return string and you must add quote on 2016618

So your code must be

```
 SELECT user.id, CONCAT(lastname, firstname), year, month, date FROM user
LEFT JOIN adoption ON user.id = adoption.adopter
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING SUM(CONCAT(year,month,date) = '2016618') = 0
```

Comment: i just find out the problem is because Mr.C & D year,month,date column are NULL, therefor sum won't return 0, but i'm still try to figure out how to write this query

Answer (score 0):

I've just try something with your result, maybe help for you.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `year` varchar(4), `month` varchar(4), `date` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `name`, `year`, `month`, `date`)
VALUES
    (16, 'Mr.A', '2016', '6', '25'),
    (17, 'Mr.B', '2016', '6', '18'),
    (18, 'Mr.C', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (19, 'Mr.D', NULL, NULL, NULL)
;

SELECT * FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(if(CONCAT(year,month,date) = 2016618, 1, 0)) = 0
```

Result:

```
| id | name | year | month | date | 
+----+------+------+-------+------+
| 16 | Mr.A | 2016 | 6     | 25   | 
| 18 | Mr.C | null | null  | null | 
| 19 | Mr.D | null | null  | null |
```